# Using "final" for a Class instantiation

Tags: dart

I came across the following code the other day (below) and wondered if it achieves anything of significance in Dart other than the fact that the Class instantiation cannot be changed. I did read some SO posts regarding Java, however they didn't appear conclusive, and don't necessarily apply to Dart. I would not have coded it that way (with final), however perhaps I should. Is there any major significance to using "final" in this instance and what does it achieve?

```
import 'dart:math';

final _random = new Random();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Dart: Up and Running](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-final-const):

> If you never intend to change a variable, use `final` or `const`, either instead of `var` or in addition to a type. A `final` variable can be set only once; a `const` variable is a compile-time constant.
>
> A local, top-level, or class variable that’s declared as final is initialized the first time it’s used.

So there are three benefits to using `final` here:

1. If some code erroneously tries to set `_random` another time, an error will be generated.
2. It is also clearer to other programmers (or the same programmer at a later date) that `_random` is never intended to be changed.
3. `_random` is not initialized until it used, so the application will start faster.

For those reasons, I would consider this a good use of `final`; certainly the code would "work" without it, but it's better this way.

In short, I think the book offers sound advice: "If you never intend to change a variable, use `final` or `const`".

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-final-const) :

*A local, top-level, or class variable that’s declared as final is initialized the first time it’s used. Lazy initialization of final variables helps apps start up faster.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll tick Darshan's because it's probably more complete. The lazy-initialization is interesting to know.

Comment: Just be aware that the documentation has changed. Local variables are now initialized with the class, not when it's first accessed.